# Debian 10 LAMP VMware apache2 (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')

Tags: php, apache2, root, virtual, lamp

I have Upload my website in the directory /var/www/html
but it does not work, the includes, require does not work at all.
Failed opening required (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')

I also use php composer but also does not work
My website’s root file does an automatic redirect to the home page, but this is an empty page
i's looks like he doesn’t recognize the path.
I tried of course to put allowoverride all in apache2, but Error 500

```
    // autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'App\\src\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
    'App\\config\\' => array($baseDir . '/config'),
);
```

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "App\\config\\":"config/",
        "App\\src\\": "src/"
      }
    }
  }
```

**index.php**

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();
// 1 instansiation de la class rooter
// 2 appel à la méthode [/download/telecharger-34082922-run run] de de class Router
$rooter = new \App\config\Router();
$rooter = $rooter->run();
```

**My rooter**

```
public function run()
    {   
        $route = $this->_request->getGet()->get('route');
        $session = $this->_request->getSession()->get('route');
        try{
            if(isset($_GET['route']))
            {
                /**
                 * etc..
                */
                else{
                    // page 404 + redirect main page
                    $this->_errorController->errorNotFound();
                }
            }
            else{ // print main page
                $this->_frontController->home();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {   
            // page 500 + redirect main page
            $this->_errorController->errorServer();
        }

            }
        }
```